# Strip <script> tags and everything in between with PHP?

Tags: php

How would I go about removing script tags, and everything inside them using PHP?

Comment: I hope you aren't trying to sanitize user input with blacklists. You'll miss `onclick`, `onmouseover`, `href="javascript:`, `src="javascript:` and many many others.

Comment: you should really attend davids hints, but to answer your question, please see my post.

Answer (score 11):

As David says, filtering only script tags is not enough if you're looking to sanitize incoming data. [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) promises to do the full package:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant 
>     HTML filter library written in 
>     PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious 
>     code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, 
>     secure yet permissive whitelist,
>     it will also make sure your documents are 
>     standards compliant, something only achievable with a 
>     comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Answer (score 9):

Go with [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as Pekka suggested.

**Never go with regex for that case**

Here is a example, regexes filters broken, works on browsers (tested on firefox)

```
<script script=">>><script></script><script>//"  >
/**/
alert(1);
</script
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
$tag_para_remover_codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador = array("head","script","style","object","embed","applet","noscript","noframes","noembed");

for ($i=0;$i<count($tag_para_remover_codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador);$i++) {

    $codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador = preg_replace("/< *" . $tag_para_remover_codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador[$i] . "[^>]*>(.*?)<\/" . $tag_para_remover_codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador[$i] . " *>/i"," ",$codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador);

}

$codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($codigo_fonte_url_dentro_buscador));
```

Comment: I think those variable names should be longer.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with the function strip_tags

http://www.php.net/strip_tags

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: NO, he cannot use that function! That function on "<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var variable;</scriprt>" will return "var variable;". He wants everything between <script ..> and </script> to be removed, as I understand.